# How do I resolve these maven 2 warnings?

Tags: maven-2, grails

I'm using Maven 2.2 with Grails 1.2.1.  When trying to run the "integration-test" target, I get some cryptic warnings, which I can't figure out how to resolve ...

davea-mbp2:socialmediaproxy davea$ mvn integration-test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for socialmediaproxy:socialmediaproxy:war:0.1
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 125, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.groupId' for net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar is missing. @ line 33, column 22
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.groupId' for net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar is missing. @ line 36, column 22
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.groupId' for net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar is missing. @ line 41, column 22
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]

Here is the part of my pom.xml the warnings are referring to ...

```
<!-- Grails defaults to Ehache for the second-level Hibernate cache. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
  <exclusions>
      <exclusion> <!-- line 33 -->
          <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion> <!-- line 36 -->
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>

      <!-- We have JCL-over-SLF4J instead. -->
      <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas how i can solve these?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a misconfiguration in your pom.xml exclusions - you need to add the groupId entries. I don't know exactly what they need to be (possibly javax.jms) but just replace the fixme as necessary.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
  <exclusions>
      <exclusion> <!-- line 33 -->
          <groupId>fixme</groupId>
          <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion> <!-- line 36 -->
          <groupId>fixme</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>

      <!-- We have JCL-over-SLF4J instead. -->
      <exclusion>
          <groupId>fixme</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for this feedback, but are the "commons-logging" and "servlet-api" exclusions you list just examples?  If not, how did you figure out these based on the warnings I got? - Dave

Comment: Never mind, I see what you mean.  Everything works.  Thanks, -